# How to unescape a default value of an input field in Thymeleaf?

Tags: forms, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am passing a model object to a view to be used in a form. Nevertheless I need to unescape one of the parameters and Springboot is throwing an error when I use `#uris.unescapePathSegment` because it can not find the relevant bean

the code

```
<tr>
    <td colspan="8"><textarea rows="15" cols="150"
        th:field="${#uris.unescapePathSegment(excerpt.comments)}" /></textarea></td>
    <td class="validation-comments" colspan="5"
        th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('excerpt.comments')}"
        th:errors="${excerpt.comments}"></td>
</tr>
```

the error

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name '#uris' available as request attribute
```

How should I solve this? Is it possible to unescape the parameter in Thymeleaf before I use it in the field or should I unescape it in the controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `th:field` can't be an expression.  It can only be a selection expression `*{...}` ([see the docs on inputs](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/thymeleafspring.html#inputs)) that points to a single field on your form-backing bean (`th:object`). If you actually do need to unescape it, it should be already unescaped by the time you get to `*{excerpt.comments}`.